# Updating permalinks in WP and .htaccess killed the non-WP subpages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Update: Woops, realized I put the code in the wrong folder. The root not the /blog/

Client is running an old version of wordpress, around 1.7 or 1.8ish.

The Blog is at:

site.com/blog/

The link format was like this:

http://www.site.com/blog/?p=1276

And I had selected to change the format to have titles based on keywords from the title:

http://www.site.com/blog/keyword1-keywords2-...-keywordX/

I then updated my .htaccess with this code generated:

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /blog/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

The result was that the subpages on the site.com that were not in the blog folder were unreachable. (the main page was reachable, and the blog did work fine with the new URLs, it just messed up the rest of the site)

Anyone have any ideas on why this might have disrupted the rest of the site and any changes I can make to the code?

Update: Woops, realized I put the code in the wrong folder. The root not the /blog/

Comment: Are the `#` intentional or did you have the wrong formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and what I had to do was go to each page and post (after the permalink structured was updated), and update each one so it will create a new url.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure that your .htaccess file has 777 permissions before changing the permalink structure within WP.